# Magento Dataflow - Export CSV

Tags: xml, magento-1.7

I have a dataflow profile to export products: name, sku, stock qty

Is it possible though to export where stock qty is not 0?

Current Code:

```
 <action type="catalog/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
</action>

<action type="catalog/convert_parser_product" method="unparse">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="url_field"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_mapper_column" method="map">
    <var name="map">
        <map name="name"><![CDATA[Name ]]></map>
        <map name="sku"><![CDATA[sku]]></map>
        <map name="qty"><![CDATA[qty]]></map>
    </var>
    <var name="_only_specified">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">true</var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/export</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[export_stock.csv]]></var>
</action>
```

Comment: Something like: <var name="filter/status"><![CDATA[1]]></var> I guess?

Comment: I tried using:     <var name="filter/qty/from"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
    <var name="filter/qty/to"><![CDATA[1000]]></var>
Using to and from values, however no result as of yet

Comment: why don't you just then open in excel/open office and filter rows with qty = 0? ;)

Answer (score 1):

In this node:

```
<action type="catalog/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
```

Replace your actions with the following lines:

```
<action type="catalog/convert_adapter_product" method="load">
    <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
    <var name="filter/qty/from"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
    <var name="filter/status"><![CDATA[1]]></var>
</action>
```

Confirmed working with Magento 1.13EE.

Comment: I should have put up the correct answer before it ported across to Magento Stack exchange. Your answer goes inline with my solution, just took a little bit of thought. Thank you